# Ajuda para consulta um única informação de um usuário do banco de dado com JSON

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Esse é o codigo que funciona com o arquivo img.php

```
function loadContato(){
    var location = $('.result_File');
    var item = "";
    $.getJSON("img.php", function(dado){
        item += '<p>' + dado[0].username + '</p>';
        item += '<img src="avatar/'+dado[0].avatar+'">';
        location.html(item);
        console.log(item);
    });
}
```

Arquivo json das informações arquivo img_trocar.php

```
[ { "avatar": "angela.jpg", "username": "angela vazquez", "email_user": "angela@gmail.com" } ]
```

Estou tendo problema com uma requisição de uma unica linha de informação do usuario

Aqui faz o seguinte mostra a foto antes do envio para o banco de dado tudo bem sem problema

```
function imagemPreview(input) {
    var imgpreview = $('#mgpreview');
    var iconAVATAR = $('.avatar');
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var filerd = new FileReader();
        filerd.onload = function (e) {
            imgpreview.attr('src', e.target.result);
        };
        filerd.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
    uploadFoto();
}
```

O problema é aqui nessa função estou tentando obiter as informações do usuario em formato JSON com o metodo $.getJSON mais como é uma unica linha não sei como fazer o for() mostra as infromações na pagina, AJUDA POR FAVOR, por segurança não vou poder mostra os dado do usuario aqui

```
function uploadFoto(){
    var items = "";
    $.getJSON('img_trocar.php', 'GET')
    .fail(function(){
        $('.result_File').html("ERRO!!");
    })
    .always(function(data){
        for(var i = 0; i < data; i++)
            {   
            items += '<img src="avatar/'+data.avatar+'" alt="avatar">';
            items += '<p>'+data[i].username+'</p>';   
            }
        $('.result_File').html(items);
    });
}
```

Comment: Tenta no `for` colocar `length` no `data`: `i < data.length`

Comment: ainda não, não mostra nada nem erro não mostra vou por o arquivo JSON para você ver

Answer (score 0):

Como é apenas um objeto JSON array de apenas 1 índice, você pode não precisa de `for`, basta chamar o valor pela chave pegando o primeiro e único índice da array (`data[0]`):

**Exemplo:**

```js
var data = [ { "avatar": "angela.jpg", "username": "angela vazquez", "email_user": "angela@gmail.com" } ],
items = '<img src="avatar/'+data[0].avatar+'" alt="avatar">'
+ '<p>'+data[0].username+'</p>';   
console.log(items);
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74054/discussion-on-answer-by-dvd-ajuda-para-consulta-um-unica-informacao-de-um-usuari)